# Channel Block API?

Tags: google-tv

Is there an API support which enables to block channels as appears in the following settings link:

> Settings -> Privacy & Safety -> Safety -> Settings -> Parentel lock -> Channel Block

Thanks!

Comment: No, please put in your request at developers.google.com/tv click on "Issue Tracker"

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, no. You can request that feature at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/